# How to get WebGL to display a dummy image in this implementation?

Tags: c#, glsl, webgl, blazor

I'm getting WebGL to initialize and everything, the following code throws no error but my dummy image (abView) is never displayed in screen space, I can only get clip space to work. Here is my code to display the image. It is using a fixed version of Blazor.Extensions.Canvas.WebGL

```
//Convert clip space to pixels
await GL.ViewportAsync(0, 0, 1280, 720);
//Fill viewport with red
await GL.ClearColorAsync(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
//await GL.ClearAsync(BufferBits.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Create texture holder
WebGLTexture glTex = await GL.CreateTextureAsync();

//Create image info
uint[] abView = new uint[64 * 64]; 


for(var i = 0; i < abView.Length; i++){ //Row
  abView[i] = (uint)255 << 24; // R
  abView[i] = abView[i] | (0 << 16); //G
  abView[i] = abView[i] | (255 << 8); //B
  abView[i] = abView[i] | 128; //A
}

//Load image info in memory
await GL.BindTextureAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, glTex);
await GL.TexImage2DAsync(Texture2DType.TEXTURE_2D, 0, PixelFormat.RGBA, 64, 64, 0, PixelFormat.RGBA, PixelType.UNSIGNED_BYTE, abView);
//abView is transformed into a Uint8Array through the Blazor extension, hence UNSIGNED_BYTE working

//Do not assume textures are a power of 2
await GL.TexParameterAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, TextureParameter.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 33071);
await GL.TexParameterAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, TextureParameter.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 33071);
await GL.TexParameterAsync(TextureType.TEXTURE_2D, TextureParameter.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, 9729);


//////Display image
await GL.UseProgramAsync(program);

//Vertex
await GL.BindBufferAsync(BufferType.ARRAY_BUFFER, texPositionBuffer);
await GL.EnableVertexAttribArrayAsync((uint)positionLocation);
await GL.VertexAttribPointerAsync((uint)positionLocation, 2, DataType.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

//Fragment
await GL.BindBufferAsync(BufferType.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
await GL.EnableVertexAttribArrayAsync((uint)texcoordLocation);
await GL.VertexAttribPointerAsync((uint)texcoordLocation, 2, DataType.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

//The render target's matrix
float[] matrix = await M4.Computations.Orthographic(0, 1280, 720, 0, -1, 1);
matrix = await M4.Computations.Translate(matrix, 20, 20, 0);
matrix = await M4.Computations.Scale(matrix, 64, 64, 0);

await GL.UniformMatrixAsync(matrixLocation, false, matrix);

//The texture's matrix
var texMatrix = await M4.Computations.Translation(0,0,0);
texMatrix = await M4.Computations.Scale(texMatrix, 1, 1, 0);

await GL.UniformMatrixAsync(textureMatrixLocation, false, texMatrix);


await GL.BeginBatchAsync();

//Clear canvas
await GL.ClearAsync(BufferBits.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

//Draw from point 0?
await GL.UniformAsync(textureLocation, 0);

//Finally, draw triangles as the image
await GL.DrawArraysAsync(Primitive.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
await GL.EndBatchAsync();
```

Here is the vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 positionLocation;

attribute vec2 texcoordLocation;

uniform mat4 matrixLocation;
uniform mat4 textureMatrixLocation;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main(void) {
gl_Position = matrixLocation * positionLocation;
v_texcoord = (textureMatrixLocation * vec4(texcoordLocation, 0, 1)).xy;
}
```

And the fragment shader:

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D textureLocation;

void main(void) {
gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureLocation, v_texcoord);
}
```

This is my vertex data:

```
  texPositionBuffer = await GL.CreateBufferAsync(); //bound to positionLocation
  await GL.BindBufferAsync(BufferType.ARRAY_BUFFER, texPositionBuffer);
  float[] positions = {0F, 0F, 0F, 1F, 1F, 0F, 1F, 0F, 0F, 1F, 1F, 1F};
  await GL.BufferDataAsync(BufferType.ARRAY_BUFFER, positions, BufferUsageHint.STATIC_DRAW);

  texcoordBuffer = await GL.CreateBufferAsync(); //bound to texcoordLocation
  await GL.BindBufferAsync(BufferType.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoordBuffer);
  float[] texcoords = {0F, 0F, 0F, 1F, 1F, 0F, 1F, 0F, 0F, 1F, 1F, 1F};
  await GL.BufferDataAsync(BufferType.ARRAY_BUFFER, texcoords, BufferUsageHint.STATIC_DRAW);
```

Comment: What are the shaders? What is your vertex data? Did you try calling `GL.GetError` at the end to double check there are no errors? Also try setting the texture matrix to just the identity as well as the other matrix. Make your posiitions a unit quad. ....

Comment: I was succesful with the identity, without trying to use screen space. Will paste the shaders. GL.GetError didn't return any error.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong except that your texture colors are reversed. red is the lower 8bits, alpha is the upper 8bits but even wrong it [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/qe7y2urm/). Since you didn't post all the code only 2 other things come to mind (1) the attribute and uniform location lookup code is wrong (2) your matrix library uses matrices transposed from how WebGL needs them. If you make a translation matrix and dump it it should be [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, x, y, z, 1] not [1, 0, 0, x, 0, 1, 0, y, 0, 0, 1, z, 0, 0, 0, 1]

Comment: One more thing that comes to mind is if your canvas is not 1280x720. You hard coded the viewport size to 1280x720 and the Ortho size instead of matching the canvas size.

Comment: That canvas is 1280x720 and the matrix dump is ok. I was successful translating and scaling in clip space (so I'm guessing the lookup code is right?). I successfully moved the 0,0 point to the top left corner so the only issue right now is the extra math matrix transformation parameters will demand so everything is between 0 and 1.

If only I could get renderDoc to work :\

Comment: Added a call to GL.ViewportAsync and  the solution must have been to make the M4 transformations to accept floats instead of ints because that's all I think there is that's different.